# No seam.quartz.properties file. Using in-memory job store

Tags: jboss, seam, jboss-eap

Al levantar un proyecto [seam](/questions/tagged/seam) con el servidor de aplicaciones [jboss-eap](/questions/tagged/jboss-eap) versión `5.1` aparece el siguiente error en el log:

```
2015-12-18 13:49:09,142 WARN  [org.jboss.seam.async.QuartzDispatcher] (main) No seam.quartz.properties file. Using in-memory job store.
```

El archivo existe y está colocado en la carpeta principal junto con el `build.xml` pero no estoy seguro de que se incluya en el proyecto al ejecutar el `explode`.

Mi archivo tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
#==============================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#==============================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName Sched1
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy false

#==============================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#==============================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount 3

#==============================================================
# Configure JobStore
#==============================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Agradecería sus amables consejos para solventar este problema de configuración.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que alguien tuvo [el mismo problema](https://developer.jboss.org/message/487636#487636) y se solucionó con un cambio sencillo.

En alguna parte tendrás `.getResourceAsStream("/seam.quartz.properties");`. Lo importante es el `getResourceAsStream` y ver que el contenido empieza con `\`.

Elimina el carácter `\` y solucionado.

Parece que al añadir el *backslash* hay algún comportamiento (que tendría que ser un bug a publicar al JIRA) extraño.